# Devexpress Gridcontrol CheckBoxRowSelect for multi selection

Tags: c#, windows, devexpress

I am using a devexpress grid.I have tried a sample for inserting and retrieving the selected rows in Gridcontrol by enabling Multiselect = true and multiselectMode=CheckBoxRowSelect.I can save and retrive the rows in grid but i cannot able to select the check box that was previously selected when binding the data to grid using datatable. The rows are grouped by Productname column.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue. I have attached the screenshot of my requirement [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm8RC.png)

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the check box that was previously selected?"  Are you just trying to get all rows that are checked?

Comment: I have got selected row using gridview.GetSelectedRows() method and saved the corresponding details in database. I have loaded data in datatable from database and binded the datatable with gridcontrol in form load event so that I can able to see the selected details while opening the form the next time. I have no idea how to bind column to MuliselectMode checkbox column. kindly help me.